# Yarn memory in emr reaching 100%?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

what is yarn memory in aws emr? How it is calculated? how to increase yarn memroy? yarn memroy reaching 100%, using r5.8xlarge with single master 2 core nodes and 2 task nodes